# How to add a <br/> to IE 10 without effecting the other browsers

Tags: html, css, list

Hi I'm sure there is a simple way of doing this but I just can't find what im looking for. 
my problem is I have an ordered list code shown below.

```
<ol>
     <li>Identification code of product type   </li>
     <b> WC flushing cistern - Class 2</b>
     <li>  Serial number allowing identification of the construction product as required under article 11(4):  </li>
     <b>   PACWHB313397</b>
     <li>Intended use in accordance with the applicable harmonised standard, as foreseen by the manufacturer   </li>
     <b>Personal Hygiene</b>
     <li>Name,  and contact address of manufacturer as required under article 11(5):           </li>
     <b>   Thomas Dudley Limited, 295 Birmingham New Road, Dudley, West Midlands, United Kingdom, DY1 4SJ  </b>
     <li>Where applicable, Name and contact details of representative who's mandate covers tasks specified in article 12(2):</li>
     <b>N/A</b>
     <li>System or Systems of assessment and verification of constancy of performance of the construction product as set out in CPR, annex V:</li>
     <b>   System 4</b>
     <li>Applicable Standards, In case of the declaration of performance concerning a construction product covered by a harmonised standard</li>
     <b>BS EN 14055:2010 WC and Urinal Flushing Cisterns (Class 2)</b>

     <b>BS 6920-2.1:2000 Suitability of non-metallic products for use in contact with water intended for human consumption.</b>

     <b>BS 1212-3:1990 Diaphragm type float operated valves (plastic bodied) for cold water services only (Excluding Floats)</b>
</ol>
```

Now in firefox it displays correctly for example it should look like this

1. example example

   **bold text here**
2. example example

   **bold text here**
3. example example

   **bold text here**

Which is working ok in all browser accept IE 10 it displays like this

1. example example **bold text here**
2. example example **bold text here**
3. example example **bold text here**

So I was just wondering is there a simple way of sorting this out using css or a certain tag to use to sort this out.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Start by fixing your errors. Use [a validator](http://validator.w3.org). Your problems are likely caused by inconsistent error recovery routines in browsers. If you write real HTML then you probably won't need to implement IE 10 specific hacks.

Comment: This is local so I cant use W3C Validator and I have wrote this using simple html there is nothing other than text on the page @Quentin

Comment: The W3C validator (a) Allows you to download it and install it locally (b) Allows you to validate a static file you upload and (c) Allows you to validate copy/pasted source code. Additionally, there are various other HTML validators on the market. "This is local" is not a good reason to not validate.

Comment: There is clearly something other than text on the page, you have `ol`, `li`, and `b` elements that we can see in the question … and you aren't using them together in a way that is allowed, hence - **use a validator**.

Comment: @Quentin I Didn't actually know W3C could Validate local files I have validated the page and trying to work out the errors at the moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Lcy2L/

You can only have `<li>` elements inside the  element. You should put all your content in the `<li>` and insert `<br />` and `<b>` or other tags to format your content inside the `<li>`.

Your code could look something like this

```
<ol>
    <li>
        Content<br />
        <b>Comment</b>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: This works Perfect @Mathias was it the way my code was.

Comment: Yes, your code wasn't valid. You shouldn't mix in `<b>` tags in the `<ol>`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, i'm not used to using tables within html usually I would use <div>'s to do all this but it was one of the requirements

Answer (score 0):

You can see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C9cne/), contains example of what you can do. with CSS:

```
.styling {
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

and li element:

```
 <li>Identification code of product type
        <br><span class="styling"> WC flushing cistern - Class 2</span>
    </li>
```